# No heat in my car

Tags: ford, coolant, explorer

My front windshield would fog up from time to time whenever I left the car which says that there's water causing moisture somewhere,  I also had to put quite a bit of coolant in with in a few months and when i stopped it felt like the air went to cold, so I decided to change the heater core and do a system flush

I ran tap water through the engine, started it up for 5 minutes then drained out the tap water. Then i put 2 1/4 gallons of 50/50 universal coolant in and a little less than 1/2 gallon of purified water because I was out of coolant, I ran the suv for 5 minutes then drained a little bit out and squeezed the hoses to get the air bubbles out, and I got a little bit of heat, when I went on a drive I got more heat but it seemed to cool down from time to time, now 3 days later it's like it only blows out fairly warm, am I missing something.

It's not overheating and it's warming up faster than it did in the past, but it's just not blowing out "hot" with a new core, there's no leaks by the water pump

It's an 02 ford explorer 6cyl 4.0

Comment: Have you checked for a stuck-open thermostat?

Comment: How can I check if it's stuck open

Comment: one site: https://www.desjardinsgeneralinsurance.com/blog/-/how-to-check-your-car-s-thermostat but also use "test car thermostat" to search for many other methods.

Comment: After you put the coolant in you stated, "*I ran the suv for 5 minutes then drained a little bit out and squeezed the hoses ...*". Why did you drain some coolant out *before* you burped it? I'll be the issue is you haven't bled the system correctly and need to do this again.

Comment: I squeezed the upper hose and I can hear air but no bubbles come out, I can also hear air seeping out the top cap, not sure if I'm suppose to heat air their

Comment: I actually think it might be my heater control valve

Comment: Is the engine warming up normally? What does the temperature gauge indicate? If it isn't warming up correctly, the fault might be the thermostat. If the engine is heating up, then either the heater control valve (which I assume controls coolant flow to the heater core) is not operating correctly, or it might be that you're not bleeding the cooling system effectively, and there's still trapped air.

Comment: @David the engine is warming up normally, I just changed the heater control valve and nothing changed, the old one was sort of sticky though, I don't know how else to.bleed the air besides push on the hoses and drive the vehicle

Comment: I'm not a Ford guy, and don't know how bleeding might be accomplished correctly. If the coolant level is full when the motor is cold, and remains so after a warm-up-and-cool-down cycle or two, then I'd say no air remains in the system. But there's another possibility, that the heater core is crudded-up and not allowing the heated coolant to flow through it. You might disconnect the core and back-flush it with a garden hose to see if stuff comes out.

Comment: @David I just got done changing out the heater core and doing a flush, the last thing it could be is a thermostat, but I find that really hard to believe that a thermostat would it allow it to blow out warm all the time, it only blows hot when I step on the gas, I'm really hoping it's not the water pump

Comment: Of all the things it might be, it isn't the water pump. If it were, then the motor would be overheating because coolant wouldn't be circulating. That leaves a) blocked heater core, b) blocked hose going to or coming from the heater core, c) stuck-open thermostat,  or d) ineffective bleeding that has left air in the heater core.

Comment: Now that I've slept on it, I think my thermostat is stuck open I don't know why I didn't catch it before, but after the tap water dill, running it for 5 minutes and then draining  it, it sucked  down 2 1/2 gallons of that 50/50 coolant and then 1/4 of a gallon later on after driving

Comment: @David update: changed the thermostat but nothing was wrong with it, wasn't stuck open, I had a heck of a time getting the old seal out then finding a new seal that an auto parts store sold for it that was big enough where it didn't leak, then I resorted to pushing on tubes and pinhole bubbles and medium size bubbles pop up every now and then but it's hell trying to get them, can those micro bubbles stop me from getting heat

Comment: And I can hear coolant flowing through the heater core when the heat and fan are on low

Comment: You should not hear coolant flowing. Thus, there's still air in the cooling system. Air in the system can interfere with heat transfer from coolant to the air passing through the heater core.

Comment: @Davis I hope it's not a head gasket sucking in air, all I got left are micro bubbles. My fingers are sore from pushing on the tubes and running the car trying to free bubbles